# What does offset mean in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What does the 'offset' parameter do in Bootsrap? For example, what is the difference between `col-sm-offset-2` and `col-sm-2`?

Comment: Docs on Bootstrap's grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comment.

Basically it pushes the cols to the right. So in your example, `col-sm-offset-2`would push the element 2 columns to the right in 'md' view. So your element kinda starts at col-3.

`col-sm-2` on the other hand just tells the element how wide it is. If you combine these 2 statements, you get an element that is pushed in 2 cols and is 2 cols wide.